# How to prevent viewing two pages in same time

Tags: php, session

I've media website once member is logged successfully it creates session

```
$_SESSION['login_id'] = $username;
```

I wonder how to prevent members to watch two channels in same time.

I mean for example if member is viewing page `video.php?id=4` and open in new tab page `video.php?id=5` it shows him error have to close the page of `video.php?id=4` before viewing the new page.

1st thing came into my mind is random `token key` that cleared on page exit but i don't know if it good idea or not, does anyone known how to do it or have better idea ! ~ thanks

Comment: how do you serve your videos? direct streaming or are you controlling the stream with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### At first thought

You could use requests to a php script that tells you if the user is still opening a web page.

For that you can use a loop of timed out ajax requests ( using  jQuery for example)

#### Hint:

Instead of making Requests you can try and load tiny images ( 1px h/w ) and of course load this image using a php script (you can trick the url using `htaccess`),
So when the image is requested, your php script will do the trick (setting the currently watched video) then serve the image (don't forget to set the proper content-type )

and keep loading the image at certain interval (you will need to generate url token to avoid caching ;) )

---

### A second solution could be

Serving your videos using php script as proxy, like that you can know when a video has been streamed completely, then if a user request a second video, knowing his is still streaming a previous one, you deny his request, show him an appropriate message or do as you like :)

> I guess, using the 2nd solution would be better for you and the visitor, since he would be able to start caching a 2nd video once the 1st one has been cached completely
>
> 1st solution will use many request which can overwhelm the network or both the client side and server side

---

#### Both Solutions would not track a user that is using more than one browser, which means he would have more than one session, unless the user is registered and logged in

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_SESSION['login_id'] = $username && COUNT($_GET['id'])>1 )
```

Now after you check this condition I don't know what you could do to prevent the user from opening 2 tabs..

Answer (score 1):

**Just my thoughts**

Since the `video has to stream, it pings the server` . The `session` can have assigned to it, the last video clicked. then once a new video is clicked, `the session on the server will use the new video id` and once the first video pings the server and find out the session is pointed at a different page, then the video can return an error message

**Alternatively**, You could assign an `ID` to each `instance` of `form` **OR** `a hidden field with an ID`, then use `AJAX` to ping the server with that ID. If the user tries to request the same form when there's an active ID, it should display an error message.